# Handle request and response between ajax and java servlet

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, servlets

I'm trying to handle the request/responde between ajax and a servlet:
The user click on a Google map marker, and through ajax he call the comment relative to the marker using his id.

this should be the Ajax code

```
 function infoCallback(infowindow, marker) {
    return function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'commentListener',
            data: {
                id: marker.id,
                comment:$('#comment').val()
            },
            success:function(data){
                var comment = $('#output').html(data);
                infowindow.setContent(comment);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        });
    };
}
```

and this should be the Servlet code

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    long id = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("id"));
    String comment = //comment relative to the id
    /*Way to send the comment to the infowindow*/
    response.getWriter().write("{comment:"+comment+"}");
}
```

Sorry if all this is not so clear!

Comment: What you are doing is you send the id and comment to the servlet and then you send back the comment. Is that the required behavior? If yes, in the success function you should do data.comment to set the content

Answer (score 1):

(Answered by the OP in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> **SOLVED**
>
> Using PrintWriter

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    long id = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("id"));
    String comment = //get comment by id
    try {  
        PrintWriter out;
        out = response.getWriter();  
        out.print(comment);
    } catch (IOException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
}
```

> and this is the ajax

```
function infoCallback(infowindow, marker) {
    return function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'commentListener',
            data: {
                id: marker.id,
            },
            success:function(result){
                infowindow.setContent(result);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        });
    };
}
```